# Как правильно организовать структуру файлов исходного кода для проекта на C++

Tags: c++, чистый-код

Хочу написать небольшой проект на C++, но ознакомившись с некоторыми проектами уже написанными на этом языке, заметил, что доминирует подход размещения файлов исходного кода, когда все файлы складываются в одну папку. Мне кажется это не очень удобно, т.к. всегда пытался разбивать проект на модули.
Вопрос заключается в следующем, считается ли размещение всех файлов исходного кода в одной директории хорошей практикой? И есть ли альтернативные способы размещения файлов исходного кода, чтобы в них как можно меньше путаться ?

Comment: Какую планируете использовать систему сборки? Например у QMake и Cmake есть подпроекты

Comment: Скажу честно, я новичок на столько, на сколько это возможно, системы сборки никогда не использовал, по крайней мере явно. До этого писал немного на Си, использовал gcc все компилировал и линковал вручную)

Comment: Никакого доминирующего подхода к размещению файлов нет. Причем безотносительно создания подпроектов. Запихивают кто во что горазд. В С++ мне представляется рациональным подход а-ля boost, когда все исходники раскладываются по папкам в соответствии с именам пространств имен.

Comment: Посмотрите в сторону популярных проектов на githab. Все используют примерно +- один и тот же принцип размещения файлов: *h, *.cpp, тесты и примеры разнесены по разным каталогам.

Answer (score 2):

Вопрос спорный, поэтому изложу свои домыслы.

1) Во-первых файловая структура должна отражать архитектурные решения примененные в проекте.

2) Интерфейсные файлы (в основном заголовочные) лучше отделять от файлов реализации, размещать их в разных папках. Струтура папок с интерфейсными файлами должна соотвествовать стуктуре пространств имен. Пример:

```
// SpaceA/Foo.h    

namespace SpaceA
{
    struct Foo {...};
    void Foo();
}

// SpaceA/SpaceB/Bar.h

namespace SpaceA
{ 
    namespace SpaceB
    {
        void Bar();
    }
}

// client_SpaceA.cpp

#include <SpaceA/Foo.h>
#include <SpaceA/SpaceB/Bar.h>

SpaceA::Foo foo = ...;
SpaceA::Foo();
SpaceA::SpaceB::Bar();
```

3) Если интерфейсные файлы включают другие интерфейсные файлы то дериктивы включения должны быть в форме как в примере выше.

4) Интерфейсные файлы и файлы реализации всегда парные. Например `Foo.h` содержит интерфейс, а `Foo.cpp` реализацию. Все сущности из `Foo.h` должны быть реализованы в `Foo.cpp`, их нельзя размещать в других файлах, или в `Foo.cpp` добавлять то чего нет в `Foo.h`.

5) Заголовочные файлы могут включать (`#include`) другие заголовочные файлы, но только те которые необходимы для объявления сущностей в данном заголовчном файле. Иными словами заголовочный файл это спецификация интерфейсв, а не реализации, он не должен включать все что нужно для реализации.

Comment: Дополнительно: если вы работаете над библиотекой, то советую разнести *.h и *.cpp файлы по разным каталогам. К примеру: ./src/foo.cpp и ./include/my_lib/foo.h. Такой способ расположения *.h файлов позволит легко и понятно подключать библиотеку в других проектах: #include <my_lib/foo.h>.

Comment: согласен, об этом сказано в пункте 2)

Comment: Я б еще рекомендовал приватный класс(который работает в рамках одной библиотеки/пространства имен) размещать где-нибудь в недрах src/private/Foo.h(cpp). Такие классы подключаются только в cpp файлах.